# RewriteRule para eliminar contexto

Tags: apache

Me gustaria poder hacer una pequeña modificación mediante un RewriteRule que me permita eliminar un contexto determinado.
Por ejemplo, si el usuario ejecuta la siguiente pagina:

http://domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/

que haga una redirección a la siguiente en la que se eliminaria "/folder1" quedando:

http://domain.com/folder2/folder3/

Como se debería de hacer?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Es fácil con un poco de **[expresiones regulares](https://github.com/sanxofon/basicnlp/tree/master/regexbasico)**.

Puedes hacerlo de forma específica:

```
RewriteRule ^/folder1/(.*)/$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

También de forma más general (eliminando cualquier primer subdirectorio):

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/(.*)/$ /$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```